# Spring boot microservices doesn't work with Intelij IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I am creating a spring boot microservice project with  intelij IDEA. 
Currently I have developed three seperate   spring boot rest services as customer service, vehicle service  and spring cloud config server. Spring cloud config server is pointing to  a github repository.
The issue is sometimes above projects take more than 10 minutes to run and sometimes does't run and give an error message as **"failed to check application readystate intellij attached provider for the vm is not found"**.  I have no idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible causes:

### 1. IntelliJ IDEA and the Spring application are running in different JVMs.

There is a bug for IntelliJ IDEA regarding that:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210665

Here is short summary:

IntelliJ IDEA uses local JMX connector for retrieving Spring Boot actuator endpoint's data by default. However, it could be impossible to get local JMX connector address via attach api if Spring Boot application and IntelliJ IDEA are run by different JVMs. In this case, add the following lines to VM options of your Spring Boot run configuration:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port={some_port}
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

As mentioned in the official Oracle documentation, this configuration is insecure. Any remote user who knows (or guesses) your port number and host name will be able to monitor and control your Java applications and platform.

### 2. Prolonged time to retrieve local hostname

You can check that time using [inetTester](https://github.com/thoeni/inetTester). Normally it should take only several milliseconds to complete. If it takes a long time then you can add the hostname returned by inetTester to `/etc/hosts` file like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost winsky
::1         localhost winsky
```